# How can I clean my fiberglass tub that was cleaned with abrasives to make it white and shiny

Tags: cleaning

I used an abrasive cleaner on my new fiberglass tub.  How can I remove the stains and dullness.

Comment: Do you only want to remove stains and dullness (local repair) or do you want to renew the tub? I would recommend second one but it's up to you, and it is crucial information in order to provide you and answer.